# Sliding effect doesn't work on first tab in "ul" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

My codepen: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/ZbBdpw

Click on the "Second" and "Third" tab. The indicator slider works fine, but when you click the "First" tab, the indicator doesn't move to that first tab.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //change active
  $('.tab-menu li a').click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      //remove all active classes
      $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
      //add active class to selected li
      $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    }
  });

});

// Calculating position
$('.tab-menu li:last-child').append('<span class="indicator"></span>');

$("head").append('<style class="tabs"></style>');

function iterateLi(ord, width) {
  $('head style.tabs').append("li:nth-child(" + ord + ").active ~ li:last-child .indicator { -webkit-transform: translate3d(-" + width + "px,0,0); transform: translate3d(-" + width + "px,0,0); width: " + width + "px}");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab-menu').children('li').each(function() {
    // Iterating through the <li>s creating for each CSS
    var ord = $(this).index() + 1;
    var width = $(this).width();
    iterateLi(ord, width);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #222;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 40px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
ul li a:hover,
ul li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
ul li.active a,
ul li.active a:hover,
ul li.active:focus {
  opacity: 100;
  color: #222;
}
ul li .indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 103s;
  transition: transform 1000ms;
}




/*
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,500);

//simple animaiton mixin, read more here - http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature
@animate: { -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;  transition: all 1s ease-in-out; };

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: #222;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2px;
    margin-right: 0;
     @animate(); 
    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
    a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 5px 40px;
      color: #fff;
      opacity: .5;
      z-index: 10;
       @animate(); 
      &:hover, &:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
      &.active {
      a, a:hover, &:focus {
        opacity: 100;
        color: #222;
      }
    }
    .indicator {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        content: '';
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 103s;
        transition: transform 1000ms;
    }
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tab-menu">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change Your Jquery Code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.tab-menu li').each(function () {
            var ord = $(this).index() + 1;
            var width = $(this).width();
            $(this).click(function () {
                var width = $(this).width();
                var nextWidth = 0
                $(this).nextAll().each(function () { nextWidth += $(this).width(); });
                var widthtes = nextWidth;
                iterateLi(ord, widthtes, width);
                console.log(widthtes);
                console.log(width);
                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    //do nothing
                } else {
                    //remove all active classes
                    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
                    //add active class to selected li
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }
            });
        });
    });

    // Calculating position
    $('.tab-menu li:last-child').append('<span class="indicator"></span>');

    $("head").append('<style class="tabs"></style>');

    function iterateLi(ord, widthtes, width) {
        $('head style.tabs').append("li:nth-child(" + ord + ").active ~ li:last-child .indicator { -webkit-transform: translate3d(-" + widthtes + "px,0,0); transform: translate3d(-" + widthtes + "px,0,0); width: " + width + "px}");
    }
```

```css
ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #222;
    }

        ul li {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 0;
        }

            ul li:last-child {
            }

            ul li a {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                padding: 5px 40px;
                color: #fff;
                opacity: .5;
                z-index: 10;
                -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            }

                ul li a:hover,
                ul li a:focus {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #fff;
                    opacity: 1;
                }

            ul li.active a,
            ul li.active a:hover,
            ul li.active:focus {
                opacity: 100;
                color: #222;
            }

            ul li .indicator {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: #fff;
                content: '';
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 103s;
                transition: transform 1000ms;
            }




/*
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,500);

//simple animaiton mixin, read more here - http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature
@animate: { -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;  transition: all 1s ease-in-out; };

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: #222;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2px;
    margin-right: 0;
     @animate(); 
    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
    a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding: 5px 40px;
      color: #fff;
      opacity: .5;
      z-index: 10;
       @animate(); 
      &:hover, &:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
      &.active {
      a, a:hover, &:focus {
        opacity: 100;
        color: #222;
      }
    }
    .indicator {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        content: '';
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 103s;
        transition: transform 1000ms;
    }
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tab-menu">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWoXWy

Comment: Hi tks, it works great now, but there's one issue. Currently, the first time the page is loaded, the indicator is on the last item. I modified the code a bit and changed all the "last-child" to "first-child" instead, so that on page load, the indicator is on the first tab, but it doesn't work, even though logically, it should. Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/wKgwKK   Pls advise. Tks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have this code going off in your css:

```
li:nth-child(2).active ~ li:last-child .indicator {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-128px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-128px,0,0);
    width: 128px;
}
```

The mistake is in your main js function from where you call iterateLi:

```
function iterateLi(ord, width) {
$('head style.tabs')
    .append(
        'li:nth-child(' + ord + ').active ~ li:last-child .indicator { -webkit-transform: translate3d(-' + width + 'px,0,0); transform: translate3d(-' + width + 'px,0,0); width: ' + width + 'px}'
    );
}

$('.tab-menu').children('li').each(function () {
    var ord = $(this).index() + 1;
    var width = $(this).width();
    iterateLi(ord, width);
});
```

Now go 1 by 1.

- First li passes as: ord = 1, width = 108px
- Second li passes as:  ord = 2, width = 128px
- Third li passes as:  ord = 3, width = 113px

Now you're telling the iterateLi function to go back by 108 pixels the first time instead of 108px + 128px (combining second and first li, because they come before your last li where you have your indicator as a default location). What you are essentially doing is telling the indicator to only go back by 100px only everytime.

To fix this pass in a different variable which calculates how much you want to go left by. so the iterateLi looks like (ord, width, leftBy).

Another thing to note I wouldn't you leave your indicator in your last li. It makes no sense to make it absolute when you declare all your css relative. Put the position relative to the parent container which would be your ul tag.

Comment: Tks for the explanation!